Dual boot issue (Boot-Repair info provided)
I recently replaced Ubuntu 16.04 with Ubuntu 22.04 in my dual boot setup. I basically formatted the Ubuntu 16.04 partition, and used that space to create root, home, and swap partitions for 22.04. Ubuntu works fine, but when I try to boot into Windows, I just get a blank screen. Here is the log of Boot-Repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d9yHVD29rs/
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS on sda4
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on sdb3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] HD Graphics 530 from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic root=UUID=9804db3c-7e09-4e6b-937c-3c6bc7e7ec7d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/sda4      ext4   60G   14G   44G  24% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 2.7.1(2.7) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0003,0005,0009,0006,0007,0008,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,d2bcbf03-18c8-41a6-9d93-48dcd0ed780d,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(3,GPT,e94390f0-9d87-44f7-a52e-c3000268cf51,0x1c608000,0x7aeb800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0005* P4: SK hynix SC308 SATA 256GB BBS(HD,P4: SK hynix SC308 SATA 256GB,0x0)..BO
Boot0006* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,USB Storage Device,0x0)..BO
Boot0007* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,P1: HL-DT-ST DVDRW/BDROM CH30N,0x0)..BO
Boot0008  Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,IBA CL Slot 00FE v0106,0x0)..BO
Boot0009* P0: TOSHIBA DT01ACA200    BBS(HD,P0: TOSHIBA DT01ACA200,0x0)..BO

a7e895ae35e102411330a3e52636b457   sdb1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a7e895ae35e102411330a3e52636b457   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
4c75682f8c4ddf9ca2f68ba84c3bf240   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
13bbe79f47b4d57f791e51f5c01f7ac8   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda4    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sdb4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda4    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sdb4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda3    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda4    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb5    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda6    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 8BBD502A-B3F9-4D33-B246-9DA299CBF25B
         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048     264191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
sda2     264192  476086271  475822080 226.9G Microsoft basic data
sda3  476086272  604977151  128890880  61.5G EFI System
sda4  604977152  732977151  128000000    61G Linux filesystem
sda5  732977152  780978175   48001024  22.9G Linux swap
sda6  780978176 3907028991 3126050816   1.5T Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: B1D162C9-CCE2-4233-AE4B-FED4CED3AC56
         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdb1       2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
sdb2    1026048   1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
sdb3    1288192 471707647 470419456 224.3G Microsoft basic data
sdb4  471707648 472629247    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
sdb5  472629248 500117503  27488256  13.1G Windows recovery environment

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA2:;
1:1049kB:135MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:135MB:244GB:244GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
3:244GB:310GB:66.0GB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
4:310GB:375GB:65.5GB:ext4::;
5:375GB:400GB:24.6GB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
6:400GB:2000GB:1601GB:ext4::;
sdb:256GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA SK hynix SC308 S:;
1:1049kB:525MB:524MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:525MB:660MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:660MB:242GB:241GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:242GB:242GB:472MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:242GB:256GB:14.1GB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL      PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                  
├─sda1                                               eb4c31e7-8f8e-497d-a846-59678a4258a4            Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda2 ntfs     22EA82E5EA82B517                     1cf59acf-ec37-449f-8cf0-bf8bfc92a668 DATA       Basic data partition
├─sda3 vfat     C0A1-68DC                            e94390f0-9d87-44f7-a52e-c3000268cf51            EFI System Partition
├─sda4 ext4     9804db3c-7e09-4e6b-937c-3c6bc7e7ec7d 94c06d2c-fb7c-4233-b540-63888d8212cc            
├─sda5 swap     11b7f9b8-3f53-41e9-a8ac-88cf86475efe 6a2dae83-c5ac-4882-a620-6005eda86ce0            
└─sda6 ext4     48760130-fba7-476c-9a7b-5500b5f64b98 1fc84ede-94f0-44d6-8e65-e95e118a7663            
sdb                                                                                                  
├─sdb1 vfat     2832-741B                            d2bcbf03-18c8-41a6-9d93-48dcd0ed780d ESP        EFI system partition
├─sdb2                                               47f5fccc-031a-40ad-ad24-5dadfb676cbf            Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb3 ntfs     7E2E0FC42E0F7485                     463f002e-57a1-424e-99c7-3399e0ff6d7f            Basic data partition
├─sdb4 ntfs     54C6DF22C6DF02E2                     8d2a57b3-eac5-4847-82d1-64700bbd4579 WINRETOOLS 
└─sdb5 ntfs     08F4DFE7F4DFD552                     0fea6e9d-0cb6-446e-a8db-ff6550604490 Image      
sdc                                                                                                  
sdd                                                                                                  
sde                                                                                                  
sdf                                                                                                  

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                        138G  39% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda4                       43.2G  23% /
/dev/sda6                        1.3T   2% /home
/dev/sdb1                        463M   7% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb3                       62.1G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb3
/dev/sdb4                      146.8M  67% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
/dev/sdb5                      238.6M  98% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb5
efivarfs                        41.6K  82% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda2                      fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda4                      ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda6                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                      vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb3                      fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb4                      fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb5                      fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

===================== sda3/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 9804db3c-7e09-4e6b-937c-3c6bc7e7ec7d root hd0,gpt4 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   9804db3c-7e09-4e6b-937c-3c6bc7e7ec7d
Windows Boot Manager (on sdb1)   osprober-efi-2832-741B
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda4/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=9804db3c-7e09-4e6b-937c-3c6bc7e7ec7d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=C0A1-68DC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=48760130-fba7-476c-9a7b-5500b5f64b98 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=11b7f9b8-3f53-41e9-a8ac-88cf86475efe none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda4: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 340.729312897 = 365.855313920  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 309.919158936 = 332.773163008  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 295.567596436 = 317.363290112  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic                  1
 309.919158936 = 332.773163008  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic                  1
 295.567596436 = 317.363290112  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 307.034873962 = 329.676185600  boot/initrd.img                                3
 307.941097260 = 330.649235456  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic               1
 307.034873962 = 329.676185600  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic               3
 307.941097260 = 330.649235456  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 May 17  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda4,
using the following options:  sda3/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS entry (sda3/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)


Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu? Grub only boots working Windows. Or no chkdsk required, no bitlocker and no Windows fast startup. If you cannot boot from UEFI menu, then you need Windows repairs. Note that Windows updates may turn fast startup or bitlocker back on.

I can't boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. Let me try out what you have suggested. Do you think "Enable Legacy Option ROMs" option should be disabled if both OS are using UEFI?

I solved the issue by disabling ""Enable Legacy Option ROMs" from BIOS boot menu.

Legacy BIOS is run by the Read Only Memory (ROMs) option in the UEFI setup utility. Disable the Enable Legacy Option ROMs option from the UEFI boot menu. This will enable Windows to boot in UEFI mode.

When in UEFI boot mode, the Enable Legacy Option ROMs option will allow legacy   
option ROMs to load. Without this option, only UEFI option ROMs will load.   
This option is required for Legacy External Device boot mode.   
This option is not allowed if Secure Boot is enabled.

